# What the are forces acting on a wheel of a moving bicycle?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, angular-momentum, torque, equilibrium

For the wheel of moving bicycle or bike why is net torque $0$
i.e $\tau_{\text{NET}}=0$?

If it can be shown that the wheel is in translational equilibrium i.e. $\sum_{}^{}\vec{F}=0$ then it's also in rotational equilibrium i.e $\sum_{}^{}\vec{\tau}=0$.

**My question:-**
I was thinking how to prove the condition for translational equilibrium, and for that what are the forces that are acting on the wheel during motion?

Comment: Check this out: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bicycle_and_motorcycle_dynamics

Answer (score 1):

The net torque is only zero if the bike isn't acceleration (speeding up, down or turning).

If such a non-accelerating rolling wheel is your assumption, then you *know* as per Newton's 1st law (in its rotational version), that any torques that are present *must* exactly balance out, meaning zero net torque. Otherwise the wheel *would* accelerate. In fact, this law is all you need to justify that there is no net torque; you don't even have to look at which torques that are actually present.

If we still want to look into the torques that might be involved, then let's concentrate on just one wheel.

- You will always have **gravity** pulling down and
- the **normal force** holding up the wheel.

But these act either at every point or act through the centre of rotation. So they don't cause any torques.

If you aren't pushing the wheel forwards (not stepping on the pedal), then there is no forwards force. Then there is also no static friction force. So there are no other forces present that could cause a torque. (I am assuming rolling and not sliding.)

This is describing an idealised scenario, though. In a more realistic scenario there will be energy loss in tire, surface, axle bearings, joints, chain etc. which will slow down the motion and cause counter-acting torques.

- This might in one be called **rolling resistance**.
- Also there might be **air-resistance** and the like.

You must then push a bit in the pedals until you cause

- a **forced forwards-acting torque** that exactly balance out these counter-acting torques.

If you step too little, then there will be a non-zero net torque (that will be negative), and if you step too hard then there will be a non-zero net torque as well (which would be positive).

Answer (score 0):

Translational equilibrium is not necessary as one may be pedalling. For example, during pedalling fast, the $R\omega$ is tried to be increased, causing friction to act forward to increase v, such that v can match $R\omega$ (Hence the acceleration)

Similarly, during sudden braking of a front wheel brake bike, $\omega$ is gone , only v remains , hence friction acts backwards to reduce v, about the Centre of mass ,the torque may cause the back of the bicycle to lift up(a common occurrence on sudden braking)
(Modern bicycles are a bit more sophisticated though I don't know the exact mechanism) .

In general torque is zero to prevent a tendency to topple(again even the mg might be able to balance the above torque, that's why only 'sudden' (high friction) brakes *may* be capable to lift the bike).